# RE: Excel formula for staff training

Tags: excel

```
=IF(OR(AND(E4="Active",G4<TODAY()),ISBLANK(G4)), "Overdue", "OK")
```

That is my current formula. G4 = date they last completed training, E4 = column stating whether they are active or not - if not then I don't want it to display Overdue. If G column is blank & E column is active I want it to display Overdue.

The problem:

I have got a database of staff names, and then whether they are active, and then if they are due training. I need a formula that takes into account if they are active or not, then if the date their training is Overdue (if the date is 1 year + past the completion date of their last training) and to display this in a new column as Overdue or OK. Ok being they don't need to book training. Additionally if the G column is blank it should treat that as over a year since the last training.

So only if the staff are "active" should it display Overdue in the final column. (as well as the date of G column being over a year before the current days date).

Im struggling to get my above formula to work :/ any assistance would be much appreciated

Comment: Is it possible to add an image to help clarify ?

Comment: `=IF(OR(AND(E4="Active",G4<TODAY()-365),AND(E4="Active", ISBLANK(G4))), "Overdue", "OK")` Adding an extra `AND()` to test for an "Active employee with a blank date". Also adding the date logic to test for overdue. Alternatively: `If (E4<>"Active", "OK", If(OR(G4<Today()-365, ISBLANK(G4)), "Overdue", "OK"))`

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring leap years (for simplicity), maybe:

```
 =IF(AND(E4="Active",G4<TODAY()-365), "Overdue", "OK")
```

Comment: You may need to change `G4<TODAY()` to `H4<TODAY()`, going by OP's example (The one in his comment, the two aren't the same for whatever reason...).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit the one in my comment. H4 is meant to be G4. G4 = is the date they last completed their training in dd/mm/yy format.

Comment: Also it needs to take into account whether they are active or not, this is column E. If they are not active, they wont be overdue training